# After ASP .Net Dynamically Rendered PDF, Cannot Change Page

Tags: asp.net, session, popup-blocker

I have a page where the user enters some information. At the bottom of the page there is a checkbox that is disabled, that says they have read the PDF to be displayed. They click on a link which dynamically renders a PDF and is downloaded by the user. After downloading the PDF a Response.End() is issued, which means nothing else can be done on the page. I want to be able to enable the checkbox after the PDF is sent.

I have tried saving the data to the Session, opening a new window, and using the Session data to send the PDF from that new window. However, IE popup-blocker blocks it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried using ModalPopupExtender / AJAX but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to use jQuery/AJAX for this?  If you did you could send the request to download the PDF via the AJAX request, and then re-enable the checkbox with javascript afterwards.